# Google maps bounds not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to set the bounds of a custom Google map so that the user cannot zoom out too far (to the point where the world map starts to tile horizontally), and cannot drag too far vertically to avoid [this](http://screencast.com/t/3TB3IOT8Alb) issue.

I've added code to set the bounds, however I no longer seem to be able to drag at all (uncomment bounds code to recreate). Basically I just want the bounds to be the world map to avoid the  issue in the screenshot above. Anything obvious I've missed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

<style>
 #map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
 } // #map
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
 this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
  
 div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
 div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
 div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dark-denim-3.png)';
  
 return div;
};

var map;
var mullem = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3873733,7.4952241);

function initialize() {
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3873733,7.4952241);
 var myOptions = {
   disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoom: 2
 };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
   myOptions);
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3869012,  7.4950149);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
       map: map,
       icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
       zIndex: 999999
     });

 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850));

 // MAP BOUNDS
 /*var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(83.829945, 160.839844), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(-72.711903, -165.058594)
 );
 var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
   if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
     // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
     lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
     return; 
   }

   // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
   map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
 });*/
 // MAP BOUNDS - END
 

  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds):

> LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral, ne?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)  Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.

Your bounds are backwards:

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(83.829945, 160.839844),  // NE
         new google.maps.LatLng(-72.711903, -165.058594) // SW
);
```

should be:

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(-72.711903, -165.058594), // SW
         new google.maps.LatLng(83.829945, 160.839844)    // NE
);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5j6y63w1/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
  this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');

  div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
  div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dark-denim-3.png)';

  return div;
};

var map;
var mullem = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3873733, 7.4952241);

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3873733, 7.4952241);
  var myOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom: 2
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3869012, 7.4950149);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
    zIndex: 999999
  });

  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850));

  // MAP BOUNDS
  //   LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral, ne?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral) Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.
  var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-72.711903, -165.058594), // SW
    new google.maps.LatLng(73.829945, 160.839844) // NE
  );
  var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
      // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
      lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
      return;
    }

    // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
  });
  // MAP BOUNDS - END


  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
// #map
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: An alternative : function latlngCentre(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng((lat1 + lat2) / 2, (lng1 + lng2) / 2);
}